# Copy a range of cells and not the whole sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How can I copy only the range of cells from A1 to J47 to a new worksheet, and not the whole sheet? Thank you

```
Sub Salva()
Dim X As String 
X = "Foglio salvato n° " & Range("G3").Value
Sheets(1).Copy 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\wc074\Documents\archivi\" & X & ".xls", FileFormat:= _
xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: To copy or to keep only that range when saving As?

Comment: saving takes its name from the content of cell G3, the macro works, but I don't want the entire sheet saved but only the indicated range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub Salva()
  Dim X As String, sh As Worksheet, newWb As Workbook, rng As Range
  
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   X = "Foglio salvato n° " & sh.Range("G3").value
   
   Set rng = sh.Range("A1:J47")
   Set newWb = Workbooks.Add
   rng.Copy newWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
   newWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
   newWb.saveas FileName:="C:\Users\wc074\Documents\archivi\" & X & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8 'Excel 97-2003 Workbook
   newWb.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, the macro works, but is it possible to copy the column width too? Thank you

Comment: @John22 Please, try the updated code. It will autofit the columns in the newly created sheet...